# How to simulate location on Windows Phone 7 simulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, location-based

I want to be able to test my location-based WP7 app. How to do this on the phone simulator?
Do we have to create some kind of mockup location data first? or is there any framework available to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library called Reactive Extensions that you can use. Here is the msdn link, which has further explanation and code samples:
[Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637517%28VS.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can try Kevin D. Wolf's [GPS simulator](http://new.efficientcoder.net/2010/09/gps-simulator-for-windows-phone-7.html) for Windows Phone 7.

It will allow you to test the GPS fonctionality of your app without any GPS device.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Torr also put a mock location service out a while back. Feel free to check it out.

[Mock Location APIs from my Mix10 Talk - Peter Torr's Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ptorr/mock-location-apis-from-my-mix10-talk)